# Terminology: Argv, Invoking a program

Tags: python, terminology, argv, sys

Hy Python Community -

This is a basic terminology question about Argv and "invoke"

I'm new to python and programmring.

I was reading about the argv function in the sys module on openbookproject.com:

"The argv variable holds a list of strings read in from the command line when a Python script is run. These command line arguments can be used to pass information into a program **at the same time it is invoked**." http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch10.html

It seems really clear from the defintion, but I still wanted to double check: Does "at the time it is invoked" just mean, "when you run the program?" Would it be appropriate in a third way to say, "Argv can pass information into a program at runtime?"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that's what "invoked" means.
2. No, because "at runtime" covers the entire time window in which the process is running. It is precisely accurate to say that argv can pass information into a program at invocation.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

> Does "at the time it is invoked" just mean, "when you run the program?"

Yes. *"at the same time it is invoked"* implies that you can pass data to the program later while it is running too i.e., you can use command-line arguments (`sys.argv`) to pass data to the program *"at the same time it is invoked"* and some other means ([IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)) to pass it later e.g., via standard input while it is running.

> Would it be appropriate in a third way to say, "Argv can pass information into a program at runtime?"

No.

`argv` defines how the command line looks like to the process e.g., [`argv[0]` sets one of the name for the process (another one is derived from the path to the actual executable)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/403887/23044). On POSIX, `argv` is a parameter for [`exec*()` functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) that is passed to C `main(argc, argv)` that is the entry point for a C program.

In other words, `argv` is used to invoke (start/run) the process but as [@G Fetterman mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33727380/4279) "at runtime" may refer to the whole process running time, not only the invocation time. `argv` may be known even before the process is running and `argv` usually stays the same after the process is started.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. Consider the following code `testargs.py`:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```

When you run this script as `python testargs.py banana` you see that the result prints "banana". Note that argv[0] is the script name, any argument given after that is argv[1], argv[2] and so on. For more sophisticated use of command line arguments, consider using the Argparse module which contains options add help docs and other features.

Edit: I only covered the invoked portion, not the runtime question.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this.