# How to get the full command line that user entered?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

In the [Click](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/click) library for Python, is there a way to get the full exact command line exactly how the user had typed it in the terminal window?

Comment: The shell processes the command and passes the arguments to the program. The program in general does not have access to the exact command the user typed.

Comment: For linux you can read the bash history file: for line in open('/home/user/.bash_history'):
    print(line, end='')

Comment: Is there a reason sys,argv  doesn't work?  That will give you what was passed to the python interpreter at least.  Can you provide any details as to what you are seeking to do?

Comment: @WombatPM actually it does work.  Got completely blinkered into Click's API.  Thanks a lot!  Can you please convert your comment into an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminology: Argv, Invoking a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727355/terminology-argv-invoking-a-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sys.argv.

`sys.argv[0]` will give you the name of the script passed to the interperter.  Other command lines elements are split on whitespace into the remaining list elements.